# Array of pointers and pointer to an array of pointers 3

Tags: c++

I have written this program and I want to know if it is correct or not? What will happen in this array pInt?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    system("color 1f");

    int **pInt=new int*[2];
    int i=0,j=0;
    pInt[0]=new int[4];
    pInt[1]=new int[7];

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            pInt[i][j]=i+j;     
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(j=0;j<7;j++)
            cout<<"pInt["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]= "<<pInt[i][j]<<endl;

    cout.write("\n\n\n\n\n",5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array of pointers to `int` is `int *arr[N];`. A pointer to an array of pointers to `int` is `int *(*arr)[N];`. I see neither of these.

Comment: your first `for` loop would collapse, since `pInt[0][x]` is only defined for `x e N | x<4`. so `pInt[0][4]` would be the first `OutOfArrayBounds-Exception` .... and the second one too

Comment: @TheOneAndOnly what exception? C++ doesn't have bounds checking...

Comment: yeah.. you know what I mean :D

Comment: @TheOneAndOnly ok ok, I have commented that only to make sure he is not confused

Comment: but thw output is ok!! pInt[0][0]= 0
pInt[0][1]= 1
pInt[0][2]= 2
pInt[0][3]= 3
pInt[0][4]= 4
pInt[0][5]= 5
pInt[0][6]= 6

pInt[1][0]= 1
pInt[1][1]= 2
pInt[1][2]= 3
pInt[1][3]= 4
pInt[1][4]= 5
pInt[1][5]= 6
pInt[1][6]= 7 and does the compiler allocate according to the max index value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loops i added a little condition to check for the array index. Now the program runs okay. try it now!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    system("color 1f");

    int **pInt=new int*[2];
    int i=0,j=0;
    pInt[0]=new int[4];
    pInt[1]=new int[7];

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
         for(j=0;j<(i==0?4:7);j++)
            pInt[i][j]=i+j;     

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(j=0;j<(i==0?4:7);j++)
            cout<<"pInt["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]= "<<pInt[i][j]<<endl;

    cout.write("\n\n\n\n\n",5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works fine my friend. but what is that? j<(i==0?4:7)??? and in my program is it dangling on unlocated memory?(writting to memory contigiuos to an array but doesn't belong to it)??

Comment: thats the ternary operator of C/C++. if j ==0 then it must be the first array, return 4 otherwise return 7

Comment: ok thanx. I know that it is ternary operator but I was a bit confused with its use in your loop. but now thanx again for making it clear

Comment: thanx again it is so great explaining. so you mean: j<((i==0)?4:7) so if i (index for rows is in the first row which has only four elemnts) then j will be incremented until 4-1 only otherwisw i in the second row(7 elements) then j is incremented until 7-1. ok thnx again